# Showing that a function in a vector space is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $X$ be a vector space and consider a function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for
some $a \in X$ defined as $f_a (x) = a \cdot x$.

(i) Prove that $f_a (x) = a \cdot x$ is a linear function.
This part is super easy, as I just show that $f_a(x+y) = f_a(x) + f_a(y)$ and $f_a(rx) = rf_a(x)$.

Parts ii-iv are the parts I do not understand. Is there somewhere I can go to learn about this stuff (I guess maybe I'm just intimidated by working with functions as elements of a set)?

(ii) Let $X^{*} = \{f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f$ is linear$\}$ be the set of all linear functions from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$.
Prove that for all $f \in X^*$ there exists an $a \in X$ such that $f(x) = a \cdot x$.

(iii) Define function addition as $f + g = f(x)+ g(x)$ and function scaling as $\alpha f = \alpha f(x)$ over the set $X^{*}$.
Prove or disprove the following statement: $X^{*}$ with the defined operations is a linear vector space.

(iv) What is dimension of $X^{*}$? (I see that this would just be the dimension of the basis of the subspace created by $X$*, just not sure how to create this basis)

Comment: The definition of $f$ makes no sense!

Comment: I'll elaborate: You say that $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f_a(x):=a\cdot x$. This does not define $f$, since that would require you to define $f(x)$ for $x\in X$. You say that $a\in X$ and $f_a(x)=a\cdot x$, does this mean that $x\in X$ as well? And what is $a\cdot x$? $X$ is a vector space, so it does not need to have an inner product.

Comment: This is exactly the question I received. I am assuming that $x \in X$. Why does $X$ not need to have an inner product?

Comment: So first of all, the notion of inner product is only defined for real or complex vector spaces and not over general fields. Secondly, the definition of a vector space does not require the space to have an inner product. In fact, one major distinction between Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces is that Hilbert spaces have an inner product whereas Banach spaces need not. Also, great that you are assuming $x\in X$, but this doesn't resolve my problem with the definition of $f$ being given in terms of $f_a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the dimension of $X$ be $n$. To clarify your doubt, I will answer the question assuming that $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $b_{1}=(1,0,\ldots,0)^{T},b_{2}=(0,1,0,\ldots,0)^{T},\ldots,b_{n}=(0,\ldots,0,1)^{T}$ be the standard bases for $X$. Now, consider the functions $f_{1},\ldots,f_{n}:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows: for any $x=(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})^{T}\in X$,

\begin{eqnarray}
f_{1}(x)=x_{1},~~~~~~~\ldots,~~~~~~~f_{n}(x)=x_{n}.
\end{eqnarray}

Clearly, $f_{i}\in X^{*}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

The claim is that $f_{1},\ldots,f_{n}$ form a basis for $X^{*}$. To prove this, we need to prove two things: span and linear independence.

---

(a) Span: Consider an arbitrary $f\in X^{*}$. Suppose that

\begin{align}
f(b_{1})&=y_{1}\\\vdots\\f(b_{n})&=y_{n}.
\end{align}

Also, suppose that $A$ denotes the $n\times n$ matrix whose rows are $b_{1},\ldots,b_{n}$, and let $y=(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n})^{T}$. Then, the system

\begin{eqnarray}
Ax=y
\end{eqnarray}
has a unique solution $x^{*}=y$ (since $A$ has full rank by the virtue of the fact that $b_{1},\ldots,b_{n}$ are linearly independent). Then, we may express $f$ as

\begin{eqnarray}
f={y_{1}}f_{1}+\ldots+{y_{n}}f_{n},
\end{eqnarray}
or
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&={y_{1}}f_{1}(x)+\ldots+{y_{n}}f_{n}(x)\\&={y_{1}}x_{1}+\ldots+{y_{n}}x_{n}\\&=y^{T}x.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, $f_{1},\ldots,f_{n}$ span $X^{*}$. Also, from the above exposition, we have shown that there exists an$a\in X$ such that $f(x)=a^{T}x$ for all $x\in X$, and it is $a=y$.

---

(b) Linear independence: Suppose that for some constants $c_{1},\ldots,c_{n}$, we have $c_{1}f_{1}+\ldots+c_{n}f_{n}=0$, i.e., for all $x=(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})^{T}\in X$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
c_{1}f_{1}(x)+\ldots+c_{n}f_{n}(x)&=0.
\end{eqnarray}

In particular, this means that $c_{1}f_{1}(b_{1})+\ldots+c_{n}f_{n}(b_{1})=0$ from which we conclude $c_{1}=0$. In a similar way, we can show that $c_{2},\ldots,c_{n}$ are all zero as well. This establishes that $c_{1}f_{1}+\ldots+c_{n}f_{n}=0$ iff $c_{1}=0=c_{2}=\ldots=c_{n}$, which in turn establishes linear independence.

Thus, the dimension of $X^{*}$ is same as dimension of $X$.

The same logic can be applied to any $X$. Just take care to replace $1$ with the multiplicative identity and $0$ with the additive identity of the underlying field governing $X$.

Comment: I have not proved explicitly that $X^{*}$ is a vector space. Hope you will be able to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer! There is one thing I don't understand. How can we conclude that $c_1 =0$ (and thus $c_2,c_3...c_n$ as well)?

Comment: @Joe that is because $f_{1}(b_{1})=1$ and $f_{i}(b_{1})=0$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$. Basically, the functions $f_{i}$, $i=1,\dots,n$, have been constructed to return the $i^{th}$ component of the vector they eat.

Comment: Similarly, by using $b_{2}$, we get $c_{2}=0$ and so on.